# JS: Cant grab json key

Tags: javascript, json

I am submitting a JSON and trying to access the individual keys.

I have tried it in different ways in the meantime.

```
    const jsonData = target.getAttribute('datas');
    console.log(jsonData.id); // returns undefined

    const jsonData = target.getAttribute('datas');
    console.log(jsonData[0].id); // returns undefined

    for(let key of Object.keys(jsonData)) {
        console.log(key);
    } // returns every single letter

    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(jsonData)) {
        console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
    } // returns every single letter
```

idk why. i dont need to parse the json. Every code explain do it same like one variant of mine.

// EDIT

The JSON:

```
{"id":"adf6cfce022e4798b11f3ae6bcd8dc0f","manufacturer":"..ö..","productName":"Blue Boat XL","productNumber":"A80801902","worth":[{"currencyId":"b7d2554b0ce847cd82f3ac9bd1c0dfca","net":11.05,"gross":11.9,"linked":false,"listPrice":null,"percentage":null,"regulationPrice":null,"extensions":[]}]}
```

still no access

```
const jsonData = JSON.parse(target.getAttribute('datas'));
    console.log(jsonData.id);
```

// THE SOLUTION
// double parse LMAO

Comment: `getAttribute` will return a _string_ value. You will need to parse this as JSON first.

Comment: @CBroe thank you dude! I thought it arrives as json. Ok but in fact it doesnt change anything. The returns are the same. idk why.. i checked so much code explains...

Comment: It would definitely help if we had some sample markup we could reproduce the issue on

Comment: @Vivick idk what exactly you mean, but i added the json upside

Comment: We need to know what the HTML part looks like to know if you're not simply reading from the wrong attribute, or the wrong element

Comment: you can be safe thats all correct. i checked already.

Answer (score 2):

sounds like you haven't parsed the data - I'm guessing `jsonData` is actually a string as a result.
You need to use JSON.parse to convert the string into an object.

try:

```
const jsonData = JSON.parse(target.getAttribute('datas'));
console.log(jsonData);
```

.. and see what you get.

Comment: Thanks for that. In fact, you are right. Thought it was arriving as JSON because I'm also passing it as JSON. 

But it doesn't change anything. I can't access the key 'id' for example.